# Apigateway spring cloud con Springboot no ve los microservicios

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estoy ampliando mis conocimientos y para ello he creado una aplicacion con un  config service y perfiles, ahora estoy añadiendo un  api gateway el cual responde con un 404, estoy creando la siguiente configuracion siguiendo la documentacion oficial, os muestro como lo estoy implementando por si alguien ve algo y me puede ayudar:

la ruta la monta de la siguiente forma:

**Archivo    base.yml**

```
            server:
              servlet:
                context-path: /dac
```

**Archivo      base-prod.yml**

```
    perfil:
  prueba: Perfil de produccion
server:
  port: 9900
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        reactive:
          enabled: false
        locator: 
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: business
          uri: http://localhost:9903/dac/
          predicates:
          - Path=/deliver/business/**
        - id: invoice
          uri: http://localhost:9901/dac/
          predicates:
          - Path=/deliver/invoice/**
        - id: customersworkers
          uri: http://localhost:9902/dac/
          predicates:
          - Path=/deliver/customersWorkers/**
```

Aqui muestro la configuracion del micro

**Archivo         business.yml**

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /dac
```

**Archivo            business-prod.yml**

```
perfil:
  prueba: Perfil de business produccion
server:
  port: 9903
```

**controlador del micro:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/deliver/business")
public class BusinessController {

    @Value("${perfil.prueba}")
    private String perfil;
    
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        
        System.out.println(perfil);
        
        return perfil;
        
    }
}
```

adjuto unas peticiones realizadas con  postman contra el micro: y otra contra el gateway

```
        GET : http://localhost:9903/dac/deliver/business/index  
        response: Perfil de business produccion
        

        
        
        
        GET: http://localhost:9900/dac/deliver/business/index 
        response:
        
            {
                "timestamp": "2023-01-21T09:46:29.478+00:00",
                "path": "/dac/deliver/business/index",
                "status": 404,
                "error": "Not Found",
                "message": null,
                "requestId": "d72e3aa1-6"
            }
```

¿alguna idea de que puede estar pasando? a primera vista siguiendo la documentacion de spring cloud parece que esta bien pero no veo que puede estar pasando. Las consolas de los micros no muestran ningun error.  gracias de antemano

```
        Ampliar mis conocimientos
```

Comment: solo para aclarar con apigateway te refieres a `Amazon API Gateway`?

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema, en mi caso el problema era que utilizaba una dependencia equivocada en el APIGATEWAY...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>        
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

cuando debía de ser sin "-mvc"...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>        
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```